# participles at the same time

Tags: participles, adjective-order

While I was reading a magazine, I saw a sentence that makes me think about orders, placements of the participles.

> Anyone caught playing faced fines and even potential jail time.

I think that the present participle should be placed between "anyone" and "caught. Who was caught ? The answer is anyone playing.

Is there an absolute rule related to which participle comes first or both of them could come first ?

Comment: It's correct as it is. It has the same meaning as "Anyone who was caught playing faced fines ..."

Comment: "Anyone playing caught faced fines"? The rules for placement are not tied to the lexical nature of the words (i.e., in this case that they're verbs in general and participles specifically), but depend on the function the words play in the sentence. If you put "playing" between "anyone" and "caught," you get a parse that makes *caught* the object of "playing," as in "playing poker." Which fails for the obvious reason.

Comment: There is no participle, really. The who was is implied: Anyone who was caught playing.

Comment: Yes, there is. "Caught playing" is a past-participial clause modifying "anyone". There's no 'implied' "who"; it's a different clause type, not a hybrid relative one. Even in the relative "anyone who was [caught playing]", "caught playing" is a past-participial clause functioning as complement of "was".

Answer (score 1):

It is correct as it is.

> Anyone caught playing faced fines and even potential jail time.

You *could* say "anyone *who was* caught...", but "anyone caught" is arguably better in this context, as it carries more certainty.

Consider warning signs like "thieves will be prosecuted". It wouldn't be quite as effective if it said "thieves who are caught will be prosecuted" as it hints that there are some who *don't* get caught and get away with it. The more succinct it is, the more serious it comes across.